# Scripts no longer work after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, sinatra

There is a table on a page which I update over ajax. There are some scripts those use content of a table. For instance, one of them uses "`Check all / Uncheck all`" checkBox on a table to `check/uncheck` the other checkboxes on that table.

When I do an ajax request, it returns almost **the same** content of a table. At least, it's **definitely correct** and should not destroy the functionality of the scripts. However, after that none of the scripts no longer work. Why?

For example, here is the part of a javascript code at *.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#check-all").change(function(){
      $(".my_table input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

Before executing ajax, request everything is working well. Note that ajax doesn't return any javascript code, all javascript code is located in an external js file.

Comment: `.change()` wont work for content added using AJAX (ie elements added after event handler is bound) - have a look at [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are using an event handler that is added on document.ready and anything added after it will not have the events.

After jQuery 1.7, you can use on.

```
$(document).on("change", "#check-all", function(){ ... });
```

other option is to keep what you have, just recall the code when you update the page's content.

```
function addChangeEvent() {
  $("#check-all").change(function(){
      $(".my_table input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    addChangeEvent();
});
```

and with your Ajax call

```
$("#foo").load("xxx.html", function(){ addChangeEvent()l });
```

Comment: Is that so? Everything added after it has exactly the same ids and classes.

Comment: @Alexandre, it does not matter. You remove the event handlers when you replace it. The browser does not magically know how to reapply it.

Comment: <<other option is to keep what you have>> Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

The event is attached to the old page content. If you replace that content, the events go with it.

Instead, try using `$("#check-all").on("change",function() {...});` I'm no jQuery expert, but I believe that will persist the event handler even if the element changes.